# Maximum of a B-spline

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, polynomials, approximation-theory, interpolation, splines

Given $p+2$ nondecreasing (and not all identical) knots $t_0, \ldots, t_{p+1}$ on the real line, consider the normalized B-spline of degree $p$ defined over these knots.

We know that the B-spline is nonnegative. Where is its maximum, and what is its value?

If the knots are equispaced, the maximum is assumed at $(t_0 + t_{p+1})/2$. What is known about its value?

Comment: I don't know the answer. But the first derivative is a b-spline of degree $p-1$ over the same knots, so finding its zero should not be too difficult (there will only be a single zero).

Comment: @bubba That is true, however the involved expressions become rather involved very quickly, and I don't know of a way to do it generically for all values of $p$.

Answer (score 4):

Using the recursive derivative formula (see for example [here](http://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-derv.html)):
$$N'_{i,p}(t) = \frac{p}{t_{i+p}-t_i} N_{i,p-1}(t) - \frac{p}{t_{i+p+1}-t_{i+1}} N_{i+1,p-1}(t)$$
We get that the maximum is achieved when:
$$f(t) = \frac{N_{0,p-1}(t)}{t_{p}-t_0} - \frac{N_{1,p-1}(t)}{t_{p+1}-t_{1}} = 0$$
This corresponds to the intersection point of two basis functions of degree $p-1$, which lies in the interval $[t_1, t_p]$. Since the ratio between the denominators ${t_{p}-t_0}$ and ${t_{p+1}-t_1}$ can be arbitrary, I don't see a way to narrow it further than that..

So the problem now becomes finding the (single) root of this equation.

One way to proceed is to use a bisection method over the $\{t_i\}$ knot values, and once the root knot interval is isolated you're in polynomial territory and can use any univariate [polynomial root method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm#Finding_roots_of_polynomials) you like, or just continue with the bisection inside the interval.

Regarding the value of the maximum, for the general case, I don't see any simpler way than evaluating the basis function at the root point.
However, for the special case of equispaced knots, the root is at $(t_0 + t_{p+1})/2$ as you correctly noted, and there is some symmetry that might be used to simplify some of the expressions.

The basic recursive function for B-Spline basis functions is:
$$N_{i,p}(t) = \frac{t-t_i}{t_{i+p}-t_i} N_{i,p-1}(t) + \frac{t_{i+p+1}-t}{t_{i+p+1}-t_{i+1}} N_{i+1,p-1}(t)$$
For the rest of the answer I assume for simplicity that $t_i = i$, this enables to derive expressions that involve only integer numerators and denominators.
The basis functions become simpler:
$$N_{i,p}(t) = \frac{t-i}{p} N_{i,p-1}(t) + \frac{i+p+1-t}{p} N_{i+1,p-1}(t)$$
Note that this recursion implies that the denominator of the value is always the factorial $p!$ (since you can factor $\frac{1}{p}$ out in every level of the recursion).

The case where $p$ is odd is simpler since the root falls on a knot and specifically on the middle knot $t_{\frac{p+1}{2}} = (p+1)/2$. Assigning the above recursive function to the knots (omitting the denominator) results in a nice "Pascal-triangle-like" pattern:
$$
\begin{array}{{13}{c}}
p=1 &&&&&0&&1&&0&&&&\\
p=2 &&&&0&&1&&1&&0&&&\\
p=3 &&&0&&1&&4&&1&&0&&\\
p=4 &&0&&1&&11&&11&&1&&0&\\
p=5 &0&&1&&26&&66&&26&&1&&0&\\
\end{array}
$$
Each row in the triangle above represents the (numerator of the) values of the basis function at the knots. The values for row $p$ in the triangle are computed with the recursive formula (the start and end values are zero by definition):
$$V_p[k] = k V_{p-1}[k] + (p+1-k) V_{p-1}[k-1]  , k=1..p$$
This recursive relation is derived directly from the basis recursive formula above.

The maximum value (finally) for the odd cases is then $\frac{V[(p+1)/2]}{ p!}$. For example, for $p=3$ the maximal value is $\frac{4}{3!} = \frac{2}{3}$ and for $p=5$ it is $\frac{66}{5!} = \frac{11}{20}$.

EDIT: Turns out this triangle has a respectable name - "Euler's Triangle". See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number) and this [MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/124358/123142) for its nice properties.

For the even case, the derivation is a little more complicated, since the maximal value is achieved at the middle of the middle knot interval, namely at $(p+1)/2$, which is now no longer integer. To compute this value we evaluate the values at half-points (namely at the $p+3$ points $-0.5, 0.5, 1.5, ..., p+0.5, p+1.5$).
Similar to the integer solution the recursive formula results in an integer numerator and denominator, however the denominator here is $2^p p!$ since we deal with half-points. The resulting triangle is:
$$
\begin{array}{{13}{c}}
p=1 &&&&0&&1&&1&&0&&&\\
p=2 &&&0&&1&&6&&1&&0&&\\
p=3 &&0&&1&&23&&23&&1&&0&\\
p=4 &0&&1&&76&&230&&76&&1&&0&\\
\end{array}
$$
Each row in the triangle above represents the (numerator of the) values of the basis function at the $p+3$ half points above. The values for line $p$ are computed with the recursive formula (the start and end values are zero by definition):
$$V_p[k] = (2k-1) V_{p-1}[k] + (2p+3-2k) V_{p-1}[k-1]  , k=1..p+1$$

The maximum value (finally finally) for the even cases is then $\frac{V[(p+2)/2]}{2^p p!}$. For example, for $p=2$ the maximal value is $\frac{6}{2^2 2!} = \frac{3}{4}$ and for $p=4$ it is $\frac{230}{2^4 4!} = \frac{230}{384}$.